# How to pass arguments to a constraint defining function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am having an objective function 'fun' and an equality constraint 'ceq(x)' which are non-linear in 'x'(1x2 vector). The issue is that 'ceq' cannot be directly written, i.e., it has to use some variables defined in the main code. This is the function code.

```
function [c,ceq] = circlecon(x)
c = (x(1)-1/3)^2 + (x(2)-1/3)^2 - (1/3)^2;
ceq = [];
```

And this is a part of the main code where I want to find the optimum 'x'.

```
nonlcon = @circlecon;
x = fmincon(fun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlcon)
```

I want to pass some variables from the main code to the function 'circlecon' and use them to define 'ceq'. How can I do that? For further information and clarification, please have a look at this link : [Optimisation with non-linear constraints](http://in.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html#busow0u-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
x = fmincon(fun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,@(x) nonlcon(x, arg1, arg2)
```

Where `arg1`, `arg2` are the extra arguments. Note that this is well documented by Mathworks.

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis and the constraint function is not specified correctly. The anonymous function should be: `@(x)nonlcon(x, arg1, arg2)`. This [link passing extra parameters](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/passing-extra-parameters.html) might also help.

Comment: @horchler: true, I did not have MATLAB handy to try it. Thanks for the correction (fixed).